# Как продолжить работу цикла?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, return

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Number8 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {-6, 2, 5, -8, 8, 10, 4, -7, 12, 1};
        int target = -2;

        doubleIndex(arr, target);
    }
    public static void doubleIndex(int[] arr, int target){
        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = arr.length - 1;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        while (startIndex != endIndex){
            int currentSum = arr[startIndex] + arr[endIndex];

            if(currentSum < target) startIndex += 1;
            else if(currentSum > target) endIndex -= 1;
            else {
                System.out.println(arr[startIndex] + " " + arr[endIndex]);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Not find!");
    }
}
```

Данный код находит сумма каких элементов массивов = -2. Если нет таких то выводит "Not find!". Если есть - выводит их. После вывода работа кода завершается, но есть еще пара элементов, у которых сумма равна -2. Можно ли как-то продолжить поиск элементов? Недавно начал учить Java, прошу описать подробно.

Comment: Убрать return..

Comment: гениально, как я не додумался!!
попробуй и убери.

Comment: Ты не додумался, потому что "Недавно начал учить Java". И если будешь так относиться к людям, которые помогают тебе, то долго здесь не протянешь.

Comment: Я очень благодарен людям, которые действительно помогают, а не таким советчикам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто убрать `return`, получится бесконечный цикл.

Следует изменить как минимум один из индексов после обнаружения целевого значения.  Если менять оба индекса, то надо будет изменить условие в цикле `while (startIndex < endIndex)`.

Также не помешает завести флажок/счётчик соответствующих пар, чтобы не выводилось некорректное сообщение после цикла.

```java
public static void doubleIndex(int[] arr, int target) {
    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = arr.length - 1;
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int findCount = 0;
    while (startIndex < endIndex) {
        int currentSum = arr[startIndex] + arr[endIndex];

        if (currentSum < target) startIndex++;
        else if (currentSum > target) endIndex--;
        else {
            System.out.println(arr[startIndex] + " " + arr[endIndex]);
            startIndex++;
            endIndex--;
            findCount++;
        }
    }
    if (findCount == 0) {
        System.out.println("Target not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше решение.

Answer (score -1):

Nowhere Man всё исправил, чтобы работало, но я не удержалась немножко, чтобы не поправить сам код. Сорри))) Если тут много, чего вам сейчас не понятно про Java, то лучше пока не вникать) Не могла пройти мимо)

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { -6, 2, 5, -8, 8, 10, 4, -7, 12, 1, 14, 8, 13, -20, -40, -25, -20, 17, 18, -15, -22 };
    int targetSum = -2;

    List<Pair> pairs = findPairsWithTargetSum(array, targetSum);
    printPairsWithTargetSum(pairs, targetSum);
}

private static List<Pair> findPairsWithTargetSum(int[] array, int targetSum) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = array.length - 1;
    Arrays.sort(array);

    List<Pair> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (startIndex < endIndex) {
        int currentSum = array[startIndex] + array[endIndex];

        if (currentSum < targetSum) {
            startIndex++;
        }
        else if (currentSum > targetSum) {
            endIndex--;
        }
        else {
            Pair pair = new Pair(array[startIndex], array[endIndex]);
            result.add(pair);

            startIndex++;
            endIndex--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static void printPairsWithTargetSum(List<Pair> pairs, int targetSum) {
    System.out.println("Пары чисел, сумма которых равна " + targetSum + ":");
    for (Pair pair : pairs) {
        System.out.println(pair.getFirst() + " и " + pair.getSecond());
    }

    if (pairs.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Не нашлось таких =(");
    }
}

private static class Pair {
    private int first;
    private int second;

    public Pair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Здравствуйте, +- понимаю ваш код, объясните, пожалуйста, почему ваш вариант можно назвать исправленным кодом, в чем его преимущество над решением Nowhere Man

Comment: Спасибо за важный вопрос! В основном, соблюдение правил соглашения о кодировании (Java code convention) (стиль кода, переносы строк, фигурные скобки, по одному оператору на одной строке и т.д.), а также приведение кода к такому виду, в котором его проще понимать как самому, так и другим людям. Здесь это достигается с помощью разделения ответственностей между методами (метод doubleIndex() и находит, и выводит пары, а лучше, чтобы за это отвечали 2 разных аспекта), именования методов и переменных так, чтобы намерения были прозрачны, плюс создание класса для пары чисел для более чёткой структуры